# Draw a binary tree in the console with the given array representation

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to draw a binary tree in the console

the tree should look like that (the tree is not complete, just representing the left side):

```
                      23
                     /   
                   15   
                  /  \
                7     8   
               / \   / \
              3   4 4   8
             / \   \
            1   2   2
               / \   \
              1   2   2
                 / \
                1   1
                   / \
                  D   S
```

here is an example how a tree can look like, but i need to represent it in the console
[image: heres an example how a tree can look like]

my input data is like that:
the input data can be any size and length. The function should handle any length

```
[23,[[15,[[7,[[3,[[1,"u"],[2,[[1,"D"],[1,"S"]]]]],[4," "]]],[8,[[4,[[2,[[1,"k"],[1,"n"]]],[2,"a"]]],[4,[[2,"e"],[2,"i"]]]]]]],[8,[[4,[[2,"r"],[2,"s"]]],[4,[[2,"t"],[2,"z"]]]]]]]
```

I already tried this

```
function drawBinaryTree(treeData, depth = 0) {
    if (!Array.isArray(treeData) || treeData.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    const value = treeData[0];
    const children = treeData[1];

    // Print the current node with proper indentation
    console.log(`${' '.repeat(depth * 3)}${value}`);

    // Draw the left and right subtrees
    if (Array.isArray(children)) {
        for (const child of children) {
            drawBinaryTree(child, depth + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

but I only achieved this:

```
    23
   15
      7
         3
            1
            2
               1
               1
         4
      8
         4
            2
               1
               1
            2
         4
            2
            2
   8
      4
         2
         2
      4
         2
         2
```

Comment: What if, in your example, either of the 4's in the 4th row had a left child?

Comment: you are right, my example tree is missing some informations. of course there can be a left child and the tree needs to be expanded

Comment: "i need to represent it in the console": that is my question: how do you *want* this to be represented in the console?

Comment: i want to represent it like i visualized it in the example under 
"the tree should look like that (the tree is not complete, just representing the left side):"

Comment: Show what you would expect to appear on your console for the second example.